# How to define 3 conditions at the same time using while loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, while-loop

I want to my domain between 0 and 1 ,  I write while loop if x is not between 0  and 1, the codes continue until x value is between 0 and 1. It works! However, I add third condition, if input is empty , continue until , value is between 0 and 1.

```
    while 1

    if xw>1 || xw <0  || isempty(xw)
  prompt = {'order of the element:','the shape function number',...
'the x coordinate'};
title = 'Input';
dims = [1 35];

definput = {'','',''};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,title,dims,definput)
p=str2double(answer(1)) %convert string to double
n=str2double(answer(2)) %convert string to double
xw=str2double(answer(3)) %convert string to double
    else
        break
    end


end
```

Comment: maybe the `xw` is not empty. Of course, we can not know because you did not show the relevant code

Comment: In the workspace xw=NaN, ın the dialog box, ı leave that part as empty

Comment: As you answered yourself: you can not choose what means empty and what does not. Just read the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
    while 1

    if xw>1 || xw <0 ||  isnan(xw) 
  prompt = {'order of the element:','the shape function number',...
'the x coordinate'};
title = 'Input';
dims = [1 35];

definput = {'','',''};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,title,dims,definput)
p=str2double(answer(1)) %convert string to double
n=str2double(answer(2)) %convert string to double
xw=str2double(answer(3)) %convert string to double
    else
        break
    end


end
```